# how to make a frosted glass effect?

Tags: html, css

I am making a site and want a fosted glass effect, any help is welcome, I have tried blur and other things but am struggligng
the html to aply it to is

```
<div class="frostedhere">
    <p> this is in the box</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a codepen to it
https://codepen.io/Person2356/pen/ZEvZMKE?editors=1100
the divs with the container and card are what will make it work
html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <p><b>hello people </b></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `background-image:`and adding an image of some frosted ice. If you want to add it overtop, add the image then make a z-index of 2, and change the opacity to maybe 0.5.

```
.frostedhere{
  background-image(url"image location or url here");
  z-index:2;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```css
.frostedhere{
  background-image:url("https://previews.123rf.com/images/miramiska/miramiska1606/miramiska160600143/58708185-gel-de-glace-d-hiver-fond-gel%C3%A9-texture-de-verre-de-fen%C3%AAtre-d%C3%A9poli-fond-froid-de-gla%C3%A7ons-frais-sc%C3%A8ne-.jpg");
  z-index:2;
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<div class = "frostedhere">
<p> placeholder </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, the other user @Addy Schroeders helped e with the codepen but thanks

Comment: I edited the post to add a code snippet, it should be working better now @user18934919